# Can you set Visual Studio's "smart indent" to not remove tabs in blank lines?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tabs

When Visual Studio (2005) has *Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs -> Indenting* set to Smart it will automatically indent code blocks and line up squiggly brackets, {}, as expected. However, if you hit enter inside a code block, move the cursor to another line, and then move it back, the inserted tabs are gone and the cursor is positioned all the way to the left. Is there a way to set Visual Studio to keep these tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do that is to enter something (anything) on that line, then delete it.  Or hit space and you'll never see it there until you return to that line.

Once VS determines that you've edited a line of text, it won't automatically modify it for you (at least, not in that way that you've described).

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoyance to myself as well. Anytime the code is reformatted the blank lines are de-tabbed.
You might look at this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac4d4d6b-b017-4a42-8f72-55f0ffe850d7 it's not exactly a solution but a step in the right direction